# Formatting English Translation in Foreign Dialogue

Tags: punctuation, translation, dialogue, german, formatting

This short paragraph of German dialogue needs to be translated into English within a larger work:

> “Zurück bleiben! Fenster schliessen!” *Stay back! Close the window!* shouted the man on the roof.

Two questions:

1) I've formatted with italics to indicate the English translation. Is this the correct?

2) Should the second sentence use an exclamation point after "Close the window" or a comma? Should it read

> *Stay back! Close the window!* shouted the man on the train

or

> *Stay back! Close the window,* shouted the man on the roof.

Comment: See (for 1) https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/1743, **perhaps** suggesting: “Zurück bleiben! Fenster schliessen!” shouted the man on the roof. _Stay back! Close the window!_ **Or as is.**

Comment: A second exclamation point is certainly grammatical, and in my opinion is much better.

Comment: My link above also suggests that the last exclamation point is fine.

Comment: Where does "shouted the man on the roof" come from? Is that clause in the original, or has it been added as a translator's note? Also, thought you haven't given much context to know what kind of text this is, normally the translation for a bit of foreign text would be given in a footnote, or the translation would be given in line with the original in a footnote.  Not sure why you've chosen to "inline" the translation.

Comment: @TRomano Well, if it is a novel (for example), then I generally wouldn't expect footnotes.

Comment: @KeepTheseNotes My feeling is, an inline translation like this would interfere with suspension of disbelief in a work of fiction.

Comment: @Spencer Well, perhaps think of it as the occasional subtitles in a film (when a German character shouts something in a film for an English audience).

Answer (score 2):

If this is a novel directed to an English-speaking audience, you'd expect to see the German in italics, not the English translation, and you might see it like this:

> *Zurück bleiben*! *Fenster schliessen!* shouted the man on the roof. "Stay back! Close the window!"

And if it is a novel, you have latitude to do pretty much as you like.

> The man on the roof was shouting  "*Zurück bleiben*! *Fenster schliessen!*" Stay back. Close the window.

You could include the exclamation marks or not; it would depend on what your narrator was thinking, and you're in control of that.

Comment: My problem with this is that quotation marks imply, well, a quotation. That what was actually said. The German here is what is actually shouted. So, the quotation marks should be around that.

Comment: The use of italics is different from when the shouter uses a foreign language to him/her. For example: ""I shouldn't use an _argumentum ad hominem_," he said." I see no reason to italicise the German if it shouted by a German speaker who is speaking plain German at the time.

Comment: @Keep these mind:  That's the way it is often done, whether you see no reason to do it or not. For example, the Spanish words in Hemingway's *The Old Man and the Sea* are in italics. They're also inside double-quotation marks. But in a novel where speech isn't quoted, for example Joyce's *Ulysses*, you'd find just the italics.

Comment: I think those are bad examples. Unless I am mistaken, _The Old Man and the Sea_ is about Cubans. It is written _as if_ they speak English. Otherwise every dialogue would have to be translated. ("[T]he novel is an English version of the Spanish that
Santiago and Mandolin would speak in real life[.]") _Ulysses_ is weird. As you say, it doesn't even use quote marks for any quote (foreign or not); and it, obviously, has other issues.

Comment: @Keepthesemind Take a more popular example, then – when we see Beauxbatons students speaking French in _Harry Potter_, their lines are in quotes and italicised as well. Similarly when we see Italian/French/Latin in Dan Brown books, it’s italicised. I think it’s perfectly common to italicise direct speech in a foreign language in novels, even if it’s not strictly necessary. The only context I can think of where it _wouldn’t_ be common is in more bilingual books: if half the lines are in L2, you’re not going to italicise half the book, that would just be silly.

Answer (score 0):

I usually italicize foreign words, insert a comma, and immediately write the English translation. I follow no authority except for what I have noticed when reading some established authors' books. However, my copy editor puts parenthesis around the English translation, but I have the final say.